# Only_if in package resource to verify whether the package is installed

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

To verify if a package is installed then run a command to remove that package can be done via the following script

```
execute 'yum -y remove prelink' do
  only_if "rpm -qa | grep 'prelink'"
end
```

However this one looks like a workaround while I'd like to use **package** resource in Chef natively.

I could do like:

```
package 'remove prelink package' do
  package_name 'prelink'
  action :remove
end
```

However, I don't know if `action :remove` perform a check before being executed. If not, I'd expect something like `only_if { ::Package.installed?(‘prelink’) }` but this doesn't seem to be the supported declaration

Comment: I think you can omit only_if, resource shouldn't fail. If you really want to use only_if you can check if package is present in `node["packages"]`.

Comment: @SzymonSzypulski would you mind to share an example of checking if package is installed using `node["packages"]`. Does Chef client really verify if we do something over attribute like this?

Comment: Something like this `not_if { node["packages"].find { |name, _| name == "prelink" }.nil? }`. I am not sure what do you mean by your question.